# How to use "distinct on" with doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, distinct, distinct-on

I try to use "distinct on" with doctrine but I get the following error:

> Error: Expected known function, got 'on'

```
class Report extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findForList() {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
        $queryBuilder->select('distinct on (r.parentId)')
                     ->orderBy('r.parentId')
                     ->orderBy('r.date', 'DESC');

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

How could I implement the following query?

```
select distinct on (r.parent_id)
    r.parent_id,
    r.id,
    r.name
from frontend.report r
order by r.parent_id, r.date desc;
```

---

Apparently it doesn't seem possible to do this with the query builder. I tried to rewrite my query in different ways:

```
select * from frontend.report r
where 
r.id in (
select distinct 
   (select r3.id from frontend.report r3
   where r3.parent_id = r.parent_id 
   order by r3.date desc limit 1) AS id
from frontend.report r2);
```

But doctrine doesn't support LIMIT:

```
public function findForList() {
    $qb3 = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb3->select('r3.id')
        ->from('MyBundle:frontend\report', 'r3')
        ->where('r3.parentId = r2.parentId')
        ->orderBy('r3.date', 'DESC')
        //->setMaxResults(1)
            ;

    $qb2 = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb2->select('(' . $qb3->getDql() . ' LIMIT 1)')
        ->from('MyBundle:frontend\report', 'r2')
        ->distinct(); // groupBy('r2.parentId')

    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
    $queryBuilder->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->in('rlt.id', $qb2->getDql())
    );

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I think the only solution is to use native SQL queries.

Comment: `SELECT r.parentId, r.id, r.name FROM Namespace/To/R r INDEX BY r.parentId ORDER BY r.parentId ASC, r.date DESC` should work, later entries will overwrite previous ones with same index...

Answer (score -1):

This response is for someone that yet looking for the solution in similar cases.
If you need a sample "DISTINCT" you can use:

```
$queryBuinder->select('parentId')
             ->distinct('parentId');
```

but if you want a "DISTINCT ON" you should use Native SQL instead of Query Builder, check out the manual here: [Doctrine Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Answer (score -2):

Just remove the `on` word :

```
$queryBuilder->select('distinct r.parentId')
             ->orderBy('r.parentId')
             ->orderBy('r.date', 'DESC');
```

Comment: But I need a distinct on and not a simple distinct! Also I found out that with select() we need to use from().